# Prepopulate Facebook Popup with Wall Text

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I want to create a facebook share button that when clicked opens a new window with the comment box prepopulated with text. I just want to share text, no link. Here is an image that illustrates what I am trying to do (please excuse my poor Photoshoping):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEBOA.jpg

I've messed around with sharer and the FB.ui API. Both of these are centered around sharing links. I just want to facilitate someone commenting on their own wall.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is not (supposed to be) possible in the facebook JS sdk, as it is against policy.